# Can't copy files using xcopy when running batch file with powershell from remote

Tags: powershell, batch-file, remote-server, xcopy

I'm trying to run a batch file to copy files from a remote computer (A) to a local Computer (B) - The two computers are in a workgroup and have full access to one another. I'm running the batch file with PowerShell script from the remote computer (A).
The batch file contain this command:

```
XCOPY \\buildagent01\C$\agent\_work\2\a\Bin\JobServer \\Automation\C$\QA\VLast\Backend\WinServices\JobServer
```

If I run this XCOPY command from the remote or local computer directly in the command prompt - the files are being copied, If I use powershell to run the batch file (Version.bat) that contains this command - 0 files are being copied...
this is how the PowerShell looks like:

```
#Predefine necessary information
$Username = "aaaa"
$Password = "*****"
$ComputerName = "Automation"
$Script = {\\Automation\C$\QA\Version.bat $args[0] $args[1] $args[2] $args[3] $args[4]}

$Binaries_Directory_Path = "\\buildagent01\C$\agent\_work\2\a\Bin\JobServer"
$QA_Fold = "\\Automation\C$\QA"
$Exclude = "\\Automation\C$\QA\Exclude.txt"
$Deployed_version_sufix = "1"
$BackupFoldPrefix = "BackupTo"
$Backup_Fold = $BackupFoldPrefix+$Deployed_version_sufix


#Create credential object
$SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassWord

#Create session object with this
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -credential $Cred

#Invoke-Command
$Job = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock $Script -ArgumentList $Binaries_Directory_Path,$QA_Fold,$Backup_Fold,$Exclude,$Deployed_version_sufix
echo $Job

#Close Session
Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
```

Comment: Sounds like a [double hop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/) problem.

Comment: Can you help me with the solution?

Comment: [Resolve Double Hop](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/847119/Resolve-Double-Hop-Issue-in-PowerShell-Remoting)

Comment: Read the article that I linked to you by Ashley McGlone. There are many ways around double hop, each with their drawbacks. But it's not as easy changing something in a line or two, it's an architecture design decision. Easiest solutions are to enable `CredSSP` or use `psexec.exe` instead of `invoke-command`, again with drawbacks to both.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Be careful recommending CredSSP as the solution as it has serious security consequences.

Comment: @BenH: Perfectly agreeing with you :)